# React 16.3 Context: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I'm rather new to React, so this might be a very simple thing.

Basically, I've been trying to operate modals using Context. I've set up my Context (a separate file):

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

export const ModalContext = createContext(false);
```

Imported it to my Component (using VS2017, so I get Intellisense):

```
import { ModalContext } from "../contexts/ModalContext";
```

Trying to implement it in the render method:

```
public render() {
        let table = this.state.loading
            ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
            : this._renderUrlsTable(this.state.urls);

        return <ModalContext.Provider value={this.state.isAddMode}>
            <div>
                <h1>Urls</h1> 
                <ModalContext.Consumer>
                    {val =>
                        <button disabled={val}>Button</button>
                    }
                </ModalContext.Consumer>
                {table}                
            </div>
        </ModalContext.Provider>;
    }
```

However, I receive this beauty:

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: object.

Now, I'm aware that there's a ton of similar posts, but none of the solutions I've found work. Actually, most of them point to incorrect import, which shouldn't be the case here.

My React dependencies:

1. "react": "^16.4.1",
2. "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
3. "react-hot-loader": "3.0.0-beta.7",
4. "react-modal": "3.1.13",
5. "react-router-dom": "4.1.1",
6. "@types/react": "^16.3.18",
7. "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.6",
8. "@types/react-hot-loader": "3.0.3",
9. "@types/react-modal": "3.1.1",
10. "@types/react-router": "4.0.12",
11. "@types/react-router-dom": "4.0.5",
12. "typescript": "2.9.1"

To sum up, any idea what can be causing this?

PS. For those of you who don't value their lives, I attach the stack trace.

```
invariant
localhost/dist/vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:118:15
ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.instantiateReactComponent
localhost/dist/vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:20273:23
ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount
localhost/dist/vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:29799:22
ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent
localhost/dist/vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:29690:21
Object.mountComponent
localhost/dist/vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:12868:35
ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount
localhost/dist/vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:29803:34
ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent
localhost/dist/vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:29690:21
Object.mountComponent
localhost/dist/vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:12868:35
ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren
localhost/dist/vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:34169:44
ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren
localhost/dist/vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:31157:32
```

EDIT: _renderUrlsTable code:

```
private _renderUrlsTable(urls: UrlViewItem[]) {
    this._prepareTable(urls);

    return(
    <div className='col-sm-12'>
        <table className='table'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Original URL</th>
                    <th>Code</th>
                    <th>Expiration date</th>
                    <th>Brand</th>
                    <th>Is generic NotFound page?</th>
                    <th>NotFound page</th>
                    <th>Visits</th>
                    <th>First visit</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {this.rows}
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you post `this._renderUrlsTable`?

Comment: @PANAYIOTIS It calls for more methods and some subcomponents. Removing it doesn't help either, but sure.

Comment: Are we sure that this is the component causing the issue? what if you return just a `<div/>` from your `render()` method, does the error go away?

Comment: @PANAYIOTIS, yes, this wasn't happening before implementing Context. I've had the app up and running for a few days now.

Comment: Well I've replicated the exact code you've written https://codesandbox.io/s/p98mpvy5nx and there's no error. Not sure what's missing from the question but something is.

Comment: Could it be a Typescript issue?

Comment: I don't think so. The error is pretty self explanatory, in the render method it expected a `string`, react class component, or functional component but got an `object` which doesn't know how to render. (Typescript: https://codesandbox.io/s/8nl9638lz8)

Comment: Can you ensure that react and react-dom are both on `16.4.1` and try deleting `node_modules` and `npm install` again?

Comment: Yes, both are on 16.4.1. Do I have to reinstall all of that manually or?

Edit: nvm, found it.

Comment: I'm asking because I can reproduce the issue if I lower `react-dom` to `16.0` (https://codesandbox.io/s/wom22ol4nl), so in case you have cached a lower version it may be causing problems (deleting `node_modules` and running `npm install` again should remove the cached copies). It could very easily be something else though

Comment: No candle :/ All my deps: https://imgur.com/a/tQrlFwp

Comment: Ok, unfortunately it's hard to help you any further without a verifiable example reproducing your issue, that at this point the best we can do is guess what the problem might be. You've seen that there is nothing wrong with the piece of code you've posted (https://codesandbox.io/s/8nl9638lz8)

Comment: Theoretically, I could probably send you the code. There's no business logic there as it's just a wrapper for a micro-service. You'd have to replace all the API calls with some mock-up data tho'. What do you think?

Comment: Work on creating the smallest example you can, removing all the irrelevant stuff on a platform like [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io). You may even discover the issue yourself while creating the example, but if not I'm sure someone else can help once they've replicated it.

Comment: Actually I've been trying to replicate it on codesandbox for a while now. Either way, thanks!

Comment: You could upload your whole code there, remove any components not part of the problem and add a link to your question

Answer (score 0):

```
export const ModalContext = createContext(false);
```

I think parameter for `createContext` should be string or undefined.

Another thing is what does the following code does:

```
{val =>
      <button disabled={val}>Button</button
}
```

This is a function, which i think is not allowed in JSX.

I am not sure but hope this fixes your issue.

Comment: Changing "false" to "undefined" in createContext clause doesn't help. Mind elaborating on the other point? I took this syntax from React's Context documentation.

Comment: `{val =>
      <button disabled={val}>Button</button>
}` is basically a function which is not supported as children of any JSX element. you can directly write `<button disabled={val}>Button</button>`, provided that you have `val` variable

Comment: Also why are you using `public` and `private` keywords in react class functions. It is not needed, please refer to react documentations for help

Comment: I've basically copied this solution from React's documentation. I'm using public and private, because I'm originally a C# developer and nothing beats a clean and clearly defined code.

Comment: [https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) where have you read `public` or `private` ?

Comment: @HridayModi He's writing Typescript not Javascript

Comment: @ᴘᴀɴᴀʏɪᴏᴛɪs Yes my bad, apologies!

Answer (score 0):

I can't confirm, but I think there is a bug in 16.3.0.  I was getting the same error; however, I reverted back to 15.6.x and all is well again.

Here's my current (reverted) react dependency list:

- "react": "15.6.1"
- "react-dom": "15.6.1"
- "react-hot-loader": "3.0.0-beta.7"
- "react-leaflet": "^1.8.0"
- "react-router-dom": "4.1.1"